# My ISP seems to be MITMing dns queries, can somene explain how they do it, technically

Tags: networking, domain-name-system

I hit this because raw.githubusercontent.com seems to have been blocked in my country
with DNS servers 8.8.8.8 or 1.1.1.1 it gets resolved to 202.83.21.15, this is an ip of my ISP and not raw.githubusercontent.com

```
$ dig +dnssec @8.8.8.8 raw.githubusercontent.com 

; <<>> DiG 9.18.10 <<>> +dnssec @8.8.8.8 raw.githubusercontent.com
; (1 server found)
;; global options: +cmd
;; Got answer:
;; ->>HEADER<<- opcode: QUERY, status: NOERROR, id: 33984
;; flags: qr aa; QUERY: 1, ANSWER: 1, AUTHORITY: 0, ADDITIONAL: 0

;; QUESTION SECTION:
;raw.githubusercontent.com.     IN      A

;; ANSWER SECTION:
raw.githubusercontent.com. 10   IN      A       202.83.21.15

;; Query time: 0 msec
;; SERVER: 8.8.8.8#53(8.8.8.8) (UDP)
;; WHEN: Fri Jan 06 11:00:10 IST 2023
;; MSG SIZE  rcvd: 84
```

Whois of the wrong IP

```
whois -H 202.83.21.15
% [whois.apnic.net]
% Whois data copyright terms    http://www.apnic.net/db/dbcopyright.html

% Information related to '202.83.21.0 - 202.83.21.254'

% Abuse contact for '202.83.21.0 - 202.83.21.254' is 'abuse@actcorp.in'

inetnum:        202.83.21.0 - 202.83.21.254
netname:        CableLite
descr:          Broad Band Internet Service Provider, India
country:        IN
geoloc:         12.984080 77.579818
admin-c:        IA145-AP
tech-c:         IT120-AP
abuse-c:        AC1823-AP
status:         ALLOCATED NON-PORTABLE
mnt-by:         MAINT-IN-ACT
mnt-irt:        IRT-CABLELITE-IN
last-modified:  2021-01-15T11:13:16Z
source:         APNIC

irt:            IRT-CABLELITE-IN
address:        Atria Convergence Technologies Pvt Ltd
address:        # 1, 2nd Floor, Indian Express Building,
address:        Queen's Road, Bangalore - 560 001
e-mail:         apnic@actcorp.in
abuse-mailbox:  abuse@actcorp.in
admin-c:        IA145-AP
tech-c:         IT120-AP
....
```

Same website when i query over DoH I get the correct ip

```
curl -H 'accept: application/dns-json' 'https://cloudflare-dns.com/dns-query?name=raw.githubusercontent.com&type=A' 2>/dev/null | jq .Answer[0]
{
  "name": "raw.githubusercontent.com",
  "type": 1,
  "TTL": 446,
  "data": "185.199.111.133"
}
```

Comment: GH has a lot of servers, which gives a lot of IPs, and those are load-balanced, are you sure it's not a Github IP?

Comment: Right, I did consider this and ran a whois for the IP, it points to my ISP. Ill update the question.

Comment: Are you sure Github doesn't have a server located in your ISP's premises?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

> how they do it, technically

The ability to define routes where to forward packets is the *core function* of routers, such as the ones that ISPs use. Normally an ISP's routers will learn all of their routes via BGP from other ISPs, but it's easy for the ISP to define a static route that forwards all packets for "8.8.8.8" in a different direction – such as to a local DNS server they've set up and assigned 8.8.8.8 as the IP address. (You can do this at home with `ip route add`.)

There are several other ways to do this; e.g. a router might support DNAT (ability to actually change the destination IP address on packets) – that's how "port forwarding" works in your home gateway, but the same kind of DNAT can be used by a router anywhere along the path to redirect packets meant for one IP address to another (e.g. rewriting "8.8.8.8" to "9.9.9.9").

Comment: even though @vidarlo has a great answer I have accepted this because it answers the "how" part of it.

Answer (score 3):

As can be seen from your response, `github.com` doesn't use dnssec.

Thus, there is no authentication of the answer, and your ISP is free to reply what they want to the query.

This can either be done by you using their DNS servers, rewriting answers from other DNS servers, or diverting all DNS traffic to their DNS servers.

Comment: Can you elaborate a bit more on the "rewriting answers from other DNS servers, or diverting all DNS traffic to their DNS servers." part?
Do you mean to say my ISP can hijack ALL my DNS queries regardless of my local settings?

Comment: "Do you mean to say my ISP can hijack ALL my DNS queries regardless of my local settings?" Yes (with default settings that will be doing DNS over TCP or UDP), which is why DNS over HTTPS and DNS over TLS were invented.

Comment: ...and dnssec. If GH used dnssec, you could discover that they were meddling.